# Symfony 4 translation are not working

Tags: symfony, translation

the problem is not symfony, is me lol, I need help cause is not working fine, when i change my locale the text is still in english, there is my code
translation.yaml

```
framework:
default_locale: '%locale%'
translator:
    paths:
        - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
    fallbacks:
        - '%locale%'
```

framework.yaml

```
framework:
secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
default_locale: en
csrf_protection: true
```

On my FrontController

```
 `/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/",
 *     requirements={"_locale"="en|es"},
 *     name="index")
 */


public function index()
{
    if($this->getUser()){
        return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
    }else{
        $register= new Register();

        $form = $this->createForm(RegisterType::class, $register,array(
            'empty_data'=>'user_register',
            'validation_groups' => array('default', 'empty_data'),
        ));
    }`
```

my messages.es.xlf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
    <body>
 <trans-unit id="sign_in">
            <source>Sign in</source>
            <target>Entrar</target>
        </trans-unit>

    </body>
</file>
```

on my template

```
{{ 'Sign in'|trans }}
```

well, the problem, is i change my url http://...../en/ to http://..../es/ is not working, but if i change my fallback manuale to es on translation.yaml is working fine, but then dons't work on /en/ any idea??

Comment: Have you tried adding the additional language to the fallbacks at the bottom of your `framework.translator` configuration?

Comment: Have you checked that you are on the right page? You are performing a redirect in your action. Maybe that is being triggered and you land on the same page, but with the default locale being used? Check your logs or the web profiler toolbar to see which route you are on and what route parameters were being used.

Comment: if I add the additional language then work but if I change the language on url still stay on spanish, i mean i am using /es work but is i change to /en stay on spanish, and the redirecction is just if the user is logged, this dont affect to locate